# how can I create a bash script for incrementing years

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to create a script for incrementing years to be used in a for loop.
if my start year is 1951 and my end year is 2010, how do i write the script so the results would be 1951-1980, 1961-1990, and so on, an increment of 30 years in ten years of interval starting from the start year until it reach 2010.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by results? Please edit your original question and add what input you provide to the script and what output you expect. Also add the code you have written and the we errors you get.

Comment: How do you intend to use these values in the loop? What will the code that you plan to put inside the body of the loop that uses the year ranges look like? I recommend that you **[edit]** this with that.

Comment: Are you looking for the output to be "1951-1980, 1961-1990" or do you want the all the numbers in those ranges printed?

Answer (score 5):

```
for y in {1951..2010..10}; do
    echo "$y-$(( $y + 29 ))"; 
done
```

Output:

```
1951-1980
1961-1990
1971-2000
1981-2010
1991-2020
2001-2030
```

Explanation:

- `{1951..2010..10}` creates a sequence of numbers as input for the loop with it's value assigned to $y.
- `$(( $y + 29 ))` calculates the end value.

---

**alternative:** (output every year like @Jeff's answer
)

```
for y in {1951..2010..10}; do
    seq $y $(( $y + 29 )); 
done
```

Output::

```
1951
1952
1953
1954
1955
1956
1957
1958
1959
1960
1961
1962
1963
1964
1965
1966
1967
1968
1969
1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1961
1962
1963
1964
1965
1966
1967
1968
1969
1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2001
2002
2003
2004
2005
2006
2007
2008
2009
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022
2023
2024
2025
2026
2027
2028
2029
2030
```

Comment: Without `seq`: `for ((y=1951;y<=2010;y=y+10)); do …` or `for y in {1951..2010..10}; do …`

Comment: I was not aware of this syntax `{1951..2010..10}`. Good one. ♥ Bash ♥ ;-)

Comment: This is `bash` Brace Expansion, see `man bash`/EXPANSION/Brace Expansion and [bash-hackers.org](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace).

Answer (score 2):

The code below will print out each year in each of the time frames you requested. You may have to change the numbers to get the exact range you want as I was unclear on how you wanted the dates to stop when it got to 2010 (hard cutoff at 2010 or continue that section until it's done then exit this does the latter).

```
#!bash 
start_year=1951
end_year=2010
j=0
year=0
while [ $year -le $end_year ]
do
    for i in {0..29}
    do
            year=$(($j+$i+$start_year))
            echo $year 
    done
j=$(($j+10))
done
```

output:

```
1951
1952
1953
1954
1955
1956
1957
1958
1959
1960
1961
1962
1963
1964
1965
1966
1967
1968
1969
1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1961
1962
1963
1964
1965
1966
1967
1968
1969
1970
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1971
1972
1973
1974
1975
1976
1977
1978
1979
1980
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
1994
1995
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
1981
1982
1983
1984
1985
1986
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
ect...
```

Comment: @Rovo I have fixed this so that it is no longer pseudo code and is now bash. Also clearly we have both interpreted OP's request differently. But I think this is what he was looking for.